# Conditional formating between columns based on date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Column L:**

[image: Column L]

**Column B:**

[image: Column B]

I want to conditionally format B if the dates in the corresponding L fall between ranges

gt 5 days away To color green attempt `=L3>TODAY()+5`

lt 5 days but gt 2 days To color amber attempt `=AND(L3<TODAY()+5,l3>TODAY()+2)`

lt 2 days To color Red attempt `=L2>TODAY()+2`

Doesn't want to work.

EDIT: FIXED FORGOT TO INCLUDE EXACTLY 5 DAYS FOR AMBER SO:
`=AND(L3<TODAY()+5,l3>TODAY()+2)`

AND OFFICE 365 WAS PLAYING SILLY BUGGERS NOT WORKING UNTIL REOPENED.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you do:

[image]

Go to `Home > Styles > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula`, then use these formulas:

**`> 5`**: `=$L3>(TODAY()+5)`

**`2 < x <= 5`**: `=($L3>(TODAY()+2))*($L3<=(TODAY()+5))`

**`<= 2`**: `=$L3<=(TODAY()+2)`

Then in the `Conditional Formatting Rules Manager`, change the `Show` to `This Worksheet` to see all the rules you made, and make sure you have this `=$B$3:$B$22` entered under `Applies to` field.

[image]

Please try and let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I managed to get it working before I saw this, but we both did similar.
One difference was I ended up using an AND condition for amber but the end result is the same.

Comment: Not a problem.  One thing that I didn't use `AND` is due to some inconsistent results (it wouldn't work) that I saw before but replacing with `*` is more reliable.

Comment: If I have issues in the future I'll bear that in mind :-)